# Not able to put space in YouTube comment

Tags: youtube, comments

This is kind of weird behaviour I am facing since last few days: while putting a comment on any YouTube video, if I add a space, then the video pauses instead of adding a space in the comment and pressing space bar again plays the YouTube video, thus not adding a space in the comment.

Also not able to navigate using arrow keys in the comment. Suppose you want to go to start of word, then only option is mouse; arrow keys are not working.

I am using Dell, with windows 10

Comment: The model of computer has nothing to do with it. The OS has a bit more bearing, but the flavor of browser you're using is important. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: As @ale said, please edit your question to include the web browser you're using, as well as other information that could be helpful. Have you tried multiple browsers? Did they all do the same thing? Has anything changed since this behavior started (i.e. new keyboard, new programs, updates, etc.)?

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate your pointers. Seems like its because of some chrome extension I installed, I checked in firefox, no issue.. Checked in chrome in incognito(off course logged into put comment in both case), no issue. Thus issue is mostly because of some chrome extension, will update which extension caused it as I find it. Thank you so much both of you

Answer (score -1):

Just happens to me in ONE tab in Firefox 86 for Linux (amd64 Debian). The other tabs in YouTube work fine, but that one video will not let me do it, even if I copy the URL, close the tab, open a new tab and paste in the URL. First time ever I see this happening and it seems like there's a few others experiencing this right now.

Answer (score -2):

I just got this problem today! I cannot type "space" in the search and the comments. But it only effects youtube on firefox and nowhere else!